# Request user to post on their facebook wall

Tags: facebook

I have a merchandising web site that allows user to buy stuff on my web site. I want to integrate this feature with facebook and enable users to allow my site to post on their wall a message showing that they have purchased an item from my web site.

How should I got about doing this. Do I need to create a facebook app to do this? Basically, I just want to enable users to accept my request to post a custom message on their walls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement the [Facebook Connect](http://www.goldsteintech.com/facebook_connect/tutorial.php) in your site so that users are able to login and you need this to publish stream to their walls.

- [See this tutorial on how to implement facebook connect](http://www.goldsteintech.com/facebook_connect/tutorial.php)

Before you publish streams to their wall, you will have to ask them for [`publish_steam` and `offline_access`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) extended permissions.

- [See this tutorial on how to get permissions](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/prompt-for-extended-permission-in-facebook-app/)

To actually post streams to their wall, have a look at [`stream.publish`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish) method.

Comment: I want to use wall post that MafiaWars and other apps use. Like in MafiaWars, if you need help to complete the mission, the app will post it on your wall. Do I also stream.publish for that?